# emulator is not reflecting the changes after changing xml

Tags: android

I was running my first android app (i am new to android). Every thing is wright.
However emulator is not reflecting the changes done in xml.

I have restarted the eclipse. Started in Debugged mode but still does not work.

Here is the output in the console:

```
[2014-01-05 02:08:00 - FirstAndroidApplication] Android Launch!
[2014-01-05 02:08:00 - FirstAndroidApplication] adb is running normally.
[2014-01-05 02:08:00 - FirstAndrod
```

Answer (score 1):

1)F5 on your project (left mouse button on needed one) in eclipse's project tree

2)menu Project-> Clean and build with running on emulator/device.

3)(optional) uninstall previous app from emulator

Answer (score 0):

try clean your project, 
If you are want to use emulator - please do yourself a favor and try Genymotion http://www.genymotion.com/ it's way more fast than the emulator that comes with adb.
actually it runs faster than debugging on a real device (on my i7 machine)

Answer (score 0):

Clear your project (In Eclipse go on Project -> Clean)

It should work.